# Subtracting Values from a Positive semidefinite Matrix in a Semidefinite Program

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, nonlinear-programming, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I'm trying to construct an SDP relaxation for a non-convex quadratic program ($x^{\intercal}\mathbf{H}x$) with the following objective function:
\begin{equation}
x_{11}y_{11} + x_{12}y_{12} + x_{21}y_{21} + x_{22}y_{22}
\end{equation}
Where $x_{ij} \in \{0, 1\}$ and $y_{\max} \leq y_{ij} \leq y_\min $ ($y_{ij}$ is a continuous\real decision variable)

The matrix $\mathbf{H}$ has the following values which makes it indefinite:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

By replacing the negative eigen values of matrix $\mathbf{H}$ with zeros and reconstructing it using the new eigen values, I got the following positive semidefinite matrix:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.2500& 0& 0& 0&0.2500& 0& 0& 0\\ 
0&0.2500& 0& 0& 0&0.2500& 0& 0\\ 
0& 0&0.2500& 0& 0& 0&0.2500& 0\\ 
0& 0& 0&0.2500& 0& 0& 0&0.2500\\ 
0.2500& 0& 0& 0&0.2500& 0& 0& 0\\ 
0&0.2500& 0& 0& 0&0.2500& 0& 0\\ 
0& 0&0.2500& 0& 0& 0&0.2500& 0\\ 
0& 0& 0&0.2500& 0& 0& 0&0.2500\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Now here is my final objective function in SDP relaxed program that I figured out so far:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H\cdot X} - \mathbf{Tr(H\cdot X})
\end{equation}

Where:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}\\x_{12}\\x_{21}\\x_{11}\\y_{11}\\y_{12}\\y_{21}\\y_{22}
\end{bmatrix}, \mathbf{X} = \mathbf{xx^{\intercal}}
\end{equation}

My questions are:

1. Are these steps correct for constructing SDP relaxation for the non-convex quadratic program?.
2. Is the objective function correct after subtracting the trace $\mathbf{Tr(H\cdot X)}$? because as far as I know the objective function must be either positive definite or positive semedefinite.
3. I know that there is a [linearization technique](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6482/solving-quadratically-constrained-quadratic-program-with-cross-product-terms-onl) that can solve the problem but I'm trying to find how this can be solved using SDP.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197664/subtracting-values-from-a-positive-semidefinite-matrix-in-a-semidefinite-program.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the best option to regard it as a non-convex QP. A product of a binary variable and a continuous variable is not really bilinear (or non-linear). For example, the nonlinear constraint
$$
z_{ij} \geq x_{ij}y_{ij}
$$
could be replaced with
$$
z_{ij} \geq y_{ij} - y_{\max}(1-x_{ij})\\
z_{ij} \geq y_{\min}x_{ij}
$$
(the RHS of the second line could be $0$ if $y_{\min}\geq 0$).