# Disjunctive Constraint , Using Binary Variable to Replace a If or condition

Tags: modeling, binary-variable, logical-constraints, big-m

I am trying to use a binary variable based on an inequality.
The value of binary variable  $q $ is 1 or 0 based on the following equation.

> [
> $q $ =
> \begin{cases}
> 0,& \text{if } b  \geq \pi  ,\\
> 1,              & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}

Here, b and $\pi$ are real numbers. Sample value b = 20 , $\pi$ = 30.

I have tried to represent this by:

\begin{equation}
q  \geq \dfrac { (\pi  - b )} {M}    
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
q \leq 1 +  \dfrac { (\pi  - b )} {M}         
\end{equation}

By using these two equations I am able to cover the cases for when $b > \pi $ and when $b < \pi $.
Unfortunately I am unable to set $q$ as 0 when $b=q$ without violating other conditions.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4473882/disjunctive-constraint-logical-constraints-using-binary-variable-to-replace-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach to this requires that $b$ be bounded, say $L \le b \le U$ for some constants $L$ and $U.$ You can come close to what you want with the following: $$b \ge \pi (1-q) + L q$$ $$b \le \pi q + U (1-q).$$ If $b > \pi,$ the second constraint forces $q=0.$ If $b < \pi,$ the first constraint forces $q=1.$ The tricky part comes when $b=\pi,$ in which case $q$ can be either 0 or 1. Because you cannot enforce a strict inequality in a MIP model, if you can't accept the ambiguity when $b=\pi$ then you can change the second constraint to $$b \le (\pi - \epsilon) q + U (1-q),$$ where $\epsilon > 0$ is a small constant. Now $$b\ge \pi \implies q=0,$$ $$b \le \pi-\epsilon \implies q = 1,$$ and $\pi - \epsilon < b < \pi$ is forbidden.

Comment: Thank You for your response. This solved the problem. The Lower Bound must be greater than both b and \pi to work , and the Upper Bound must be higher than both to work. Am  I right?

Comment: I assume you meant "less" rather than "greater" for the lower bound, in which case you are right, with the following qualification. If $L > \pi$ or $U < \pi,$ $q$ is a constant and can be eliminated from the model.

Comment: yes , thank you for the response. What if both b and $\pi$ are decision variables ,  is there any way to remove the non-linearity to model the binary variable q? i.e. model the binary variable q in a linear fashion to represent the inequality b $\geq \pi$ ?

Comment: You can linearize the product $\pi q$ with additional constraints. This is a FAQ on this forum. See, for instance, the accepted answer to https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/mixed-integer-optimization-with-bilinear-constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Professor , I was able to solve it :) You have been a great help !